# how can i run setup:upgrade and cli commands on windows

Tags: cli, setup-upgrade, windows

Hello everyone in my case i have installed Magento 2.3.4 on Windows and i need to run setup:upgrade like on Ubuntu , but it's not working for me , is this issue because on Windows we have backslash '' instead of slash '/' for paths? any help please ?

Update :
this is what happened when i run the upgrade they ask me to "how do you want to open this file" and this is not what the upgrade do normally of course :\

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what you mean by not working? please add error? and no, its not becuase of slash.

Comment: Can you share what you have try and what error you face?

Comment: when i tap bin/magento setup:upgrade , they told me select an application that  you would like to open with . so this is not the normal behavior of this command

Comment: can you see the update above (the picture) this is what happened when i run the upgrade @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try run these commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```